# ruby's Regexp.last_match global value inside method

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

Can anyone explain why the following does not work? Isn't `$~` supposed to be a *global* variable set whenever a regexp match is made?

```
class LocalizedObject < BasicObject
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash=hash
  end

  def method_missing(name, *args)
    @hash[$current_locale || "en"].send(name, *args)
  end
end

proxy = LocalizedObject.new({"en" => "foobarbaz", "pt" => "xpto"})
proxy                                        # => "foobarbaz"

# this won't work as expected

proxy.match(/f.*r/)                          # => #<MatchData "foobar">
Regexp.last_match                            # => nil
$~                                           # => nil

# which would be like this...

"foobarbaz".match(/b.*z/)                    # => #<MatchData "barbaz">
Regexp.last_match                            # => #<MatchData "barbaz">
$~                                           # => #<MatchData "barbaz">
```

EDIT: I replaced the previous simpler example with something more explanative of what I want to achieve.... I want LocalizedObject to be transparent to its users, so it can be plugged into some existing code that I don't want to change.

Can anyone think of tricks to make this work?

I'm using ruby 1.9.2 for this but I get the same with 1.8.7 and a custom `BasicObject` stolen from https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/sql.rb

Comment: Have you tried the block form of `match` as a kludge to grab `$~` before something else overwrites it? Maybe something is using a regex behind your back. Works fine without the `< BasicObject` BTW. You shouldn't be using the global state anyway, you should be using the returned MatchData.

Comment: The thing is I can't touch the code that uses `match`, this is actually why I need the proxy object in the first place, to write a transparent extension to that code. I also agree one should use the returned MatchData and not rely on these silly side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In [re.c](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/eval.c?revision=32510&view=markup), line 3453, it is mentioned:

> Note that the `last_match` is local to the thread and method scope
>   of the method that did the pattern match.

Since with your proxy object you are doing the `match` call in `method_missing` it will be visible just there as can bee seen if you change it to

```
def method_missing(name, *args)
  res = @object.send(name, *args)
  Kernel.p $~
  res
end
```

**UPDATE:**

Quite ugly, but maybe something like this is an option?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby19

def set_current_locale(l)
  $current_locale = l
  ObjectSpace.each_object { | obj |
    obj.adjust_locale if obj.respond_to? :adjust_locale
  }
end

class LocalizedObject < String
  def initialize(hash)
    super(hash[$current_locale || "en"])
    @hash = hash
  end

  def adjust_locale
    self[0..-1] = @hash[$current_locale || "en"] if @hash
  end
end

proxy = LocalizedObject.new({"en" => "foobarbaz", "pt" => "xpto"})

proxy.match(/f.*r/)                          # => #<MatchData "foobar">
Regexp.last_match                            # => #<MatchData "foobar">
$~                                           # => #<MatchData "foobar">

set_current_locale('pt')

proxy.match(/x.*o/)                          # => #<MatchData "xpto">
Regexp.last_match                            # => #<MatchData "xpto">
$~                                           # => #<MatchData "xpto">
```

Comment: OK, +1 for having found the comment in re.c that explains it (it's not there in 1.8.7's). But your first example with `send` *does* work! It only stops working after you redefine `String#send`, is that what you meant? Any ideas how to get around this?

Comment: You are right, I had messed it up completely. For a possible work-around: Can you avoid creating proxy objects for strings and just extend the `String` class?

Comment: See my edit of the original question. `LocalizedObject` should work for all kinds of objects, not just strings...

Comment: @Joao Tavora: I don't see a way to achieve this with one class. IMO, you need to create a LocalizedObject class for strings (to maintain the match functionality) and another proxy class for everything else.